# How do I attach a PDF document to an email merge using Outlook and Word

Tags: mail-merge

How do I attach a PDF document to an email merge using Outlook and Word. The merge is ready to go but I don't see a place to attach a file.

Comment: It can be done with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft's [Frequently asked questions about the mail merge feature in Word 2003, Word 2007, and Word 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826838):

> **Q15: Can I add an attachment when performing a merge to an e-mail message?**
>
> A15: No, you cannot add an attachment when performing a merge to an
>   e-mail message. Microsoft Office Word doesn’t support this
>   functionality. However, you can add an attachment when performing a
>   merge to an e-mail message programmatically by using CDOSys. You can
>   contact a solution provider to build solution for you.

There is at least one free utility to help with it though -- [Outlook Mail Merge Attachment](http://omma.sourceforge.net/) (note: never used this personally).

> *Outlook Mail Merge Attachment* supplies the mail merge process in Microsoft Office Word and Outlook with the functionality to add an
>   attachment. The script is tested on Microsoft Office 2003, 2007, 2010
>   and 2013.*